# Find the parametric equation for the tangent line to the intersection curve between an ellipsoid and a paraboloid?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, conic-sections, parametric, ellipsoids

We got various problems in this site asking for similar problems btw an ellipsoid and a plane. What if it's btw an ellipsoid and a paraboloid?

I got the equation of both surfaces: $4x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9$ and $z = x^2+y^2$ respectively. Now given the tangent line touches their intersection (as an off-origin $xz$-ellipse but this might be useless) at $(-1, 1, 2)$, how can we find the $\underline{v}$ for the parametric equation of the tangent line $\underline{r}(t) = (-1, 1, 2) + t\underline{v}$? Is there any way we need to utilize the directional derivative of either surface? Or we just use $f(x, y, z)$ and $g(x, y, z)$ to describe both surfaces so that $\underline{v} = \nabla f \times \nabla g$ which I got after simplification as $(5, 8, 6)$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The tangent line to the intersection curve is in tangent planes to both surfaces at the given point. So $\nabla f \times \nabla g$ does give you direction vector of the line.

Comment: @MathLover Would you mind to explain a bit more how we can be sure that both tangent planes would intersect at the tangent line?

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if that explains. I have also shown how we could go about it by parametrizing the intersection curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parametrize the intersection curve of both surfaces and then find the direction vector of the tangent line. But the easier approach here is what you have written towards the end of the question. Let me try and address your question on how we know that tangent planes will intersect in the tangent line. Please note that tangent lines to level curves of both surfaces passing through point $P (-1, 1, 2)$ will lie in the tangent planes to the surfaces at $P$. As the intersection curve is on both surfaces and passed through $P$, its tangent line at $P$ must be on both tangent planes. A line can only lie in two different planes if both planes intersect and it must be the line that is intersection of both planes.

Now coming to the first approach I mentioned. Given surfaces are,

$z = x^2 + y^2$
$4x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9$

At intersection, $x = \pm \frac 1 {\sqrt3} \sqrt{9 - z - z^2}, y = \pm \frac 1 {\sqrt3} \sqrt{4z + z^2 - 9}, z = z$

Looking at $P$, we parametrize the intersection curve for $x \leq 0, y \geq 0$.

$ \displaystyle r(t) = \left( - \frac 1 {\sqrt3} \sqrt{9 - t - t^2}, \frac 1 {\sqrt3} \sqrt{4t + t^2 - 9}, t \right)$

Point $P$ is represented by $t = 2$.

$ \displaystyle r'(t) = \left(\frac {2t + 1} {2 \sqrt{27 - 3t - 3t^2}}, \frac {2t + 4} {2 \sqrt{12t + 3t^2 - 27}}, 1 \right)$

$ \displaystyle r'(2) = \left(\frac 56, \frac 86, 1\right)$

So we can take the direction vector of the line as $(5, 8, 6)$ and equation of the tangent line to the intersection curve at $P$ is,

$l: (-1, 1, 2) + s ~(5, 8, 6)$

Comment: Seems legit. Also help me recall what I can get from the parametrization of arbitrary curves. By the way, is _there can only be 1 tangent line to each point on the intersection curve from both surfaces, so the tangent line must be on both tangent planes from both surfaces_ the key to why the required tangent line $\equiv$ the line where both tangent planes intersect? Thanks.

Comment: @Yuki.F yes, there will be only one tangent line to the curve at a given point on it. In general, if a function is differentiable at a point, it will have only one tangent.